# Convert MONO-16bit image with 2bytes per pixel to MONO-16bit with 1 byte per pixel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, emgucv

I am working in C# and I have a monochromatic camera returning to me two successive images. I want to subtract these images.

The camera is set to MONO-16 with resolution 1980x960.

The camera returns to me a vector of 2457600 elements, because each pixel is represented by two bytes so `{1980x960 = 1228800} * 2 bytes / pixel = 2457600`.

The problem is that I have to convert the two 2457600 element vectors to two 1228800 vectors in order to do the subtraction.

So I need to combine two successive elements of the 2457600  into one element  so that I end up with a vector of 1228800 elements, where its element have 16bit range (0-65536).

I will probably have to create a loop to iterate 1228800 times and in each iteration take two elements from the 2457600 vector:

```
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 2457600 ; i = i + 2)
  {
     byte BYTE1 = newGrabResultInternal2.ImageData.Buffer[i];
     byte BYTE2 = newGrabResultInternal2.ImageData.Buffer[i+1];        
     // What to do next to combine the 2 bytes into one???
  }
```

When I have the two bytes which represent 1 pixel, how do I combine them together to give me an intensity value of 16bit depth (0-65536)?

Also, if you can suggest a different approach it would be helpful.

Comment: Is it just a case of paired images or is it for many images as in video?

Comment: It is just two successive images for now. Later i will try to do it in real-time streaming, where i will take two successive images, and display one.

Comment: No worries.  I was just reading MS WIA because there may be something there that may do it faster using native code.  I also thought there was an Imaging SDK but I can't find it sadly

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway. thumbmunkeys solution worked so I continue with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bit operations for that:

```
for(int i=0;i<2457600;i=i+2)
{
  byte BYTE1 = newGrabResultInternal2.ImageData.Buffer[i];
  byte BYTE2 = newGrabResultInternal2.ImageData.Buffer[i+1];        

   int pixel = ((int)BYTE1 << 8) | ((int)BYTE2);
 }
```

This will shift `BYTE1` 8 bits left and then combine it with `BYTE2`.

This will make `BYTE1` the higher byte and `BYTE2` the lower. If you want it the other way around you need to swap them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!